# SQL Update Query Only Works The Second Time

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have an `UPDATE` statement in SQL script I run weekly that has been working fine for months. Until now.

Nothing has been changed in the script, but for the past couple of weeks when I run it the UPDATE doesn't update the values in all 4 fields, it only sets the values in 3 fields. But then if I highlight the UPDATE statement and run it a second time, it works fine.

I've never seen this behavior before, where a query--that was working fine all along--suddenly only works right after you run it twice. What's going on?

Here's the SQL:

```
UPDATE dbo.NEW_ACCT
SET 
dbo.NEW_ACCT.NAME1 = dbo.ACCT.NAME1,
dbo.NEW_ACCT.NAME2 = dbo.ACCT.NAME2,
dbo.NEW_ACCT.COST = dbo.ACCT.COST,
dbo.NEW_ACCT.AInd = dbo.ACCT.ACCT_IND,
dbo.NEW_ACCT.EMP_FLAG = dbo.ACCT.ACCT_FLAG,
dbo.NEW_ACCT.ACCTCONT = dbo.ACCT.ACCOUNTCONT
FROM 
dbo.ACCT
INNER JOIN
dbo.NEW_ACCT
ON 
dbo.NEW_ACCT.KEY_1 = dbo.ACCT.KEY_1
```

The first time this runs, dbo.NEW_ACCT.NAME1, dbo.NEW_ACCT.NAME2, dbo.NEW_ACCT.COST, dbo.NEW_ACCT.AInd and dbo.NEW_ACCT.EMP_FLAG get updated, but dbo.NEW_ACCT.ACCTCONT is null. Then I run the SQL again and all the fields get updated.

Comment: Can you post the entire statement? Feel free to hide any proprietary information but it'd be useful to see the code

Comment: Was there an update to the software you are using to run the query? Maybe the query is actually running fine but the reader isn't refreshing the 4th record with it's new status.

Comment: Need the code, por favor. Too many possibilities otherwise

Comment: Run your SQL Server profiler, and get the parameters passed in

Comment: No software has changed, this is simply running manually in SSMS, and has been working fine for weeks.

Comment: Is this running in isolation? Could something else be adding to your destination table while you're not looking, via another process or later in the procedure?

Comment: Have you selected the database to use? e.g. `use SOMEDATABASENAME`